# How to properly connect a 4-pin cable to the IIC interface?

Tags: pi-3

I'd like to connect a 4-pin cable to my Raspberry's IIC interface; more specifically to the SDA, SCL, and 2 ground pins, as depicted below:

[image: schema]

Right now I simply have stripped one end of my 4 pin-cable and just wrapped each wire around the relevant pin, but of course that's hardly robust.

I'd like to know what component(s) I should use to make a proper, solid connection to the IIC's pins?
Permanent solutions are fine.

If relevant, my 4-pin cable looks like this:
[image: 4_pin]

Comment: You don't need two GND pins. Simply use the 3,5,7,9 row, and don't care about GPIO4.

Comment: @Janka: ok thanks. But still, that doesn't tell me how to do proper connections :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many ways to do this. This question is about wiring harness and wire-to-board interconnect design, and there are many approaches. This is more art-of-design than any one specific solution.

### Some Possible Approaches

---

#### Extract pins from the connector

This is similar to your "bare wire" approach, but you leave the crimp pin on the wire end for a more reliable connection

> [image]
>
> Remove Pin from Housing using a sharp object
>
> [image]
>
> Use the bare crimp directly

As an additional tip, shrink tubing can be used to protect the exposed metal of the crimp pin from any accidental contact

#### Transplant into a different housing

Use larger housing to connect all the pins. For your application a 10 Pin (2x5) header will work. Simply extract the pins (as above) and re-insert them into a 10 pin housing in the appropriate locations

> [image]
>
> A 10 pin Housing

#### Create a dedicated adapter cable

Similar approach to above, but allows swapping slave devices without rewiring. Create a wiring harness that has a 4 pin male housing and to a 10-40 pin female housing.

> [image]
>
> The mating partner for your current connector
>
> [image] [image]
>
> A crimp tool and crimp pins are required

#### Use a Screw Terminals

Bare wires can be robustly attached using screw terminals, there are many HATS and adapters that allow one to use screw terminals for connecting GPIO Pins on Raspberry PI

> [image]
>
> Screw Terminal HAT

#### Create a custom adapter board or HAT

Consider creating a custom board or hat that has the appropriate connector and routes the connections to correct GPIO pins. Alternative to a custom adapter cable.